# Comparing gson JsonObject value with java String

Tags: java, json, gson

```
JsonObject json = new JsonObject();
json.addProperty("type", "hello");

System.out.println(json.get("type").toString().equals("hello"));
```

The above print statement should technically give "true" right?
But am getting "false"...am kind of novice to java..."please bare with this novice question".

Please let me know, whats wrong with the code?

Comment: try to print this `json.get("type").toString()` and mystery will be solved

Comment: Don't use `toString`, use `getAsString`.

Comment: What is the return type of that `get`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
json.get("type").getAsString();
```

The thing is that GSon `JsonObject` stores the property inside a `Map<String, JsonElement>` internally, and when you call a `JsonObject.get()` method, it returns a `JsonElement` and not the actual value.